# How do I find the number of messages a user has sent in a server Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I want to make a bounty system based on the number of messages a person has sent in the server.
Like how if we search the messages sent by a certain user, we get the results, that way, is it possible for a bot to find the number of messages sent?
I have tried finding but was unsuccessful.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a proper [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we do not write code for others here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `channel.history`, this can search through message history throughout a channel. You can set a limit to how far it finds message but it will take longer to find.

In this example, it will only look for messages the user had send and loop through the current channel. Adding a count for each message it finds

```
messages = 0
async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit = 100):
    if message.author == member:
        messages += 1

    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has sent {counter} messages in this channel.')
```

Please provide your attempts when asking a question, it shows you have put effort into asking the question and not just totally relying on the community to help. Hope this example can help you further.